# PhoneGap - Not working on new devices

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, error-handling

Hello I am working in PhoneGap Android and have released an app which works will under Android 2.3.3 in both a virtual device and actual device.

However, the app wont even get past the first page of the app when run on Android 4.1 in both a virtual device and actual device.

I am at a loss to what could be wrong as I've placed every piece of code in try blocks and none of them get triggered and the app works great in the older versions.

This is my logcat under Android 4.1

```
10-14 22:48:53.502: I/CordovaLog(871): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-14 22:48:53.502: I/CordovaLog(871): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-14 22:48:53.512: D/CordovaLog(871): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-14 22:48:53.562: D/JsMessageQueue(871): Set native->JS mode to 1
10-14 22:48:53.694: D/DroidGap(871): DroidGap.init()
10-14 22:48:53.822: D/CordovaWebView(871): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html, 10000)
10-14 22:48:53.822: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(splashscreen,show)
10-14 22:48:54.202: D/dalvikvm(871): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 3% free 8080K/8259K, paused 335ms, total 339ms
10-14 22:48:54.312: I/dalvikvm-heap(871): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.111MB for 1228816-byte allocation
10-14 22:48:54.522: D/dalvikvm(871): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 9278K/9479K, paused 201ms, total 201ms
10-14 22:48:55.032: D/dalvikvm(871): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 3% free 9283K/9479K, paused 102ms+77ms, total 440ms
10-14 22:48:56.101: D/CordovaWebView(871): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-14 22:48:56.101: D/PluginManager(871): init()
10-14 22:48:56.141: D/CordovaWebView(871): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-14 22:48:56.141: D/DroidGap(871): Resuming the App
10-14 22:48:56.192: I/Choreographer(871): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-14 22:48:56.532: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(871): Ignore this event
10-14 22:48:56.802: I/Choreographer(871): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-14 22:48:56.973: D/gralloc_goldfish(871): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-14 22:48:57.764: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(871): Ignore this event
10-14 22:48:59.602: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-14 22:49:06.772: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(871): Ignore this event
10-14 22:49:16.172: E/CordovaWebView(871): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
10-14 22:49:16.172: D/Cordova(871): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www/splash.html
10-14 22:49:16.232: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/splash.html","description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful."})
10-14 22:49:16.764: I/Choreographer(871): Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-14 22:49:16.764: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(871): Ignore this event
10-14 22:49:17.321: D/Cordova(871): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-14 22:49:17.332: D/CordovaWebView(871): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-14 22:49:17.364: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
10-14 22:49:17.364: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-14 22:49:17.386: I/Choreographer(871): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-14 22:49:49.262: D/DroidGap(871): Paused the application!
10-14 22:49:50.032: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(871): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-14 22:49:51.446: D/DroidGap(871): onDestroy()
10-14 22:49:51.446: D/CordovaWebView(871): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-14 22:49:51.472: D/CordovaWebView(871): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-14 22:49:51.642: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
10-14 22:49:51.682: W/System.err(871): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
10-14 22:49:51.682: W/System.err(871):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at org.apache.cordova.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:195)
10-14 22:49:51.702: W/System.err(871):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-14 22:49:52.302: D/Cordova(871): onPageFinished(about:blank)
10-14 22:49:52.312: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
10-14 22:49:52.312: D/DroidGap(871): onMessage(exit,null)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I am using PhoneGap version: cordova-2.1.0.js

Through some more reading I have also added this line to my MainActivity.java

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

And also have changed the ADB connection timeout to 10000 from 5000

Here is my Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.game.demo"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is your phonegap vesrion?

Comment: What does you manifest look like? It appears the CallbackServer can't create a socket.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the phonegap version and a copy of my manifest file.